# Display webpage in Android listview

Tags: android, httprequest

I would like to get the data from [here](https://www.minerva.shef.ac.uk/minerva/med/includes/inc_news_details.php?id=23165) and display it in my app.

The list view is current empty when the activity is launched and I'm not exactly sure what I need to add, I'm quite stuck. Would really appreciate any help, thanks!
Here is the relevant code:

```
public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String KEY_LINK = "link";

private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    new GetData().execute();
}

private class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... uri) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // getting intent data
        Intent in = getIntent();

        // Get JSON values from previous intent
        String link = in.getStringExtra(KEY_LINK);
        String info = null;

        final String QUERY = link;

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
        builder.scheme("https")
                .authority("www.minerva.shef.ac.uk")
                .appendPath("minerva")
                .appendPath("med")
                .appendPath("includes")
                .appendPath("inc_news_details.php")
                .appendQueryParameter("id", QUERY);


        try {

            URL url = new URL(builder.build().toString());

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                Log.d("Hello,", "Spongebob!");
                // Do normal input or output stream reading
            }
            else {
                 // See documentation for more info on response handling
            }

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            info = buffer.toString();

            List<String> details = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(info));

            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplication(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.link, details);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Hi", "This is Patrick");

            return null;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    }
}

}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What I'd do is having a Fragment with a ListView of URLs (showing the site names or descriptions). Clicking one of those ones, swap to another Fragment which has a WebView showing the passed URL.

Comment: Ahh, I have built that already. What I want to do now is display the content from here: https://www.minerva.shef.ac.uk/minerva/med/includes/inc_news_details.php?id=23165 in my app as the user clicks.

Comment: ... and what stops you?

Comment: Well, if you click on the link on my previous comment you can see the content I want to display. What is stopping me is that I don't know how to display it in my app.

Comment: As I told you, you must use a WebView.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your input. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you have to use web view instead of loading the url using HTTPURLConnection. This is because this is not a standard rest based api which returns the data in xml and json format.

In your activity_details.xml file. Remove list view and add the following view.

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/webview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

And then add following line of code in your activity.

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
browser.loadUrl("https://www.minerva.shef.ac.uk/minerva/med/includes/inc_news_details.php?id=" + mID);
```

> If still you insist to do this using ListView then you will have to
>   parse the data yourself putting hacks which is not a standard way of
>   doing it.

Comment: Alright, I've just tried it and it works. Thanks for helping me out! :)